# HTML/CSS - Responsive vertical listing in multiple columns with floating div?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've searched quite a bit but haven't found a technique for this. Not even sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hae4a90g/

In this jsfiddle example, all 9 boxes goes from left to right. It's responsive-friendly as you can have all 9 boxes on a single line or on a single column depending on your browser width.

What I'd like to do is to have the boxes being listed vertically instead. So it would show:

```
Box 1   Box 4   Box 7
Box 2   Box 5   Box 8
Box 3   Box 6   Box 9
```

If you resize your browser smaller it would show:

```
Box 1  Box 6
Box 2  Box 7
Box 3  Box 8
Box 4  Box 9
Box 5
```

I can add clear:both to the box class but then it only shows one column at all times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `column-width`. This calculates the number of columns automatically.

```css
.outer {
  column-width: 11em;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 5em;
  page-break-inside: avoid;   /* Chrome needs this */
  break-inside: avoid-column; /* IE10 and IE11 need this */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box">Box 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in jsfiddle! Don't even have to use @media, this is perfect, thanks! (doesn't work as expected with the SO button "Run code snippet" though.

Comment: That's odd. It works in Firefox, but in the other two browsers it goes wrong when there's not exactly three columns of three boxes each. Apparently I didn't test thoroughly enough - the default code snippet width shows three columns on my screen, so I thought it was OK. Sould have clicked "Full page" everywhere. Sorry!

Comment: I added `page-break-inside: avoid;` now, which makes it work as advertised in Chrome. However, still the same problem in IE11. Let me see what I can do about that.

Comment: Found it! [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside) says IE supports the `break-inside` property since v10. So, all solved.